# All static resources must be finalized and without external resource includes

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components

I am building an app using the lightning framework. In the app I am using Google charts plugin (CoreChart.js, Jsapi.js) for drawing different types of charts.
We have loaded Google charts as static resource but during security review Google charts has been flagged with following comment "All static resources must be finalized and without external resource includes". Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Jsapi downloads additional resources based off what charts you're loading. Have you checked with Salesforce to see if this is allowed? It could possibly explain your flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means you can't hotlink js code (which is a very bad practice anyways, and is blocked by many users who use browser extensions to prevent third party js loads). All js code needs to be in static resources. For whatever libraries you want to use

1. download a local copy and serve it from static resources. The CSP
   will block any resource loads from non-salesforce origins, and even if it didn't, we require the package version Id to be the unit of configuration management, so the code in a component must be self-contained within the component or within static resources.
2. If the file is minified, then provide an unminified version as well so that
   the code can be reviewed
3. You are responsible for ensuring that the code conforms to the Lightning lifecycle and for properly wiring the code to work with lightning. For example if the code clobbers global window functions, then you can't use it or need to patch it so that it doesn't interfere with other components loaded on the page. If the code modifies the DOM, then it should be run from a renderer context rather than from the controller. If the code uses animations, then it needs to check that the DOM elements still exist because your component can be unrendered at any time by the framework, etc.

In other words, this is not a "fire and forget" situation, the Lightning framework makes some rigid assumptions about the behavior of components. If these assumptions are broken, the UI will be susceptible to race conditions in which it will throw exceptions or will fail to render components properly. Therefore making sure that your components meet all the contracts of a component is mandatory, and there is no special waiver for breaking component contracts because you are including code written by someone else.

Answer (score 2):

To reference a JavaScript library that you’ve uploaded as a static resource, use a  tag in your .cmp or .app markup.

The framework’s content security policy mandates that external JavaScript libraries must be uploaded to Salesforce static resources. For more information on static resources, see “[What is a Static Resource?](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_static_resources.htm)”

Here’s an example of using :

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/resourceName"/>
```

resourceName is the Name of the static resource which you can upload under Setup->Develop->Static Resource.

Reference Document : [Using external javascript in lightning component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm)

[Implementation Tutorial](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html)

Comment: Please read the questions carefully, I have already said "We have loaded Google charts as a static resource". I have read the quide and followed the setups in it.